# Мультифильтрование ListCollectionView

Tags: c#, .net

Есть у меня некий `ListCollectionView`. В котором содержится, естественно, `ObservableCollection`, содержащий некоторые объекты. Допустим там хранятся люди которые заходят на славный ресурс StackOverFlow. Сигнатура класса такая :

```
public StackOverFlowUzer{

public string Name { get; set; }
public byte Age { get; set; }
public string Country { get; set; }
public string CodeLanguage { get; set; }
public Color HatColor { get; set; }

}
```

И мне необходимо как то отфильтровать. Но фильтрация происходит по приоритетам, давайте введем следующие приоритеты для фильтров :

```
High > Middle > Low
```

И мне необходимо применить к коллекции несколько фильтров, с разными приоритетами :

допустим фильтр по возрасту с приоритетом High
фильтр по стране, тоже с приоритетом High
фильтр по цвету шляпы приоритет Low

Все фильтры работают по стандартному принципу

```
interface IFilter<in T>{

bool Predicate(T _obj);

}
```

Есть идея класть все фильтры в SortedList по приоритету и подкладывать предикат.

Comment: Я представляю себе, что значит «сортировка по разным полям с приоритетом». Но что означает фильтрация? Не всё ли равно, в каком порядке применять фильтры?

Comment: @VladD а если ввести такое понятие как - ценность поля. Допустим нам приоритетней знать возраст человека, а не цвет его шляпы. Ценность поля прямо влияет на приоритет фильтра.

Comment: Фильтр либо возвращает запись,либо нет. Порядок применения не должен влиять на результат.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: Ну да, но это ж не влияет на конечный результат? Если мы выкинули всех мужчин и всех брюнетов, то у нас останутся в точности одни блондинки, в каком порядке бы мы не выкидывали, правильно?